# How to redirect to an url which is coming from the database in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, redirect

I have a web api built in .NET, within an endpoint i would like to redirect to an url which matches the the code inserted in database. the endpoint takes as entry the code and i am supposed to redirect to the corresponding url. For that i use the Redirect method which actually is not working. i did Console.Write to print if the url is null or empty but it exists. here is the code of my controller :

```
     [HttpGet("{hash}")]
    // [ProducesResponseType(302)]
    //[ProducesResponseType(404)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> redirectUrl(string hash)
    {
        var t = await new ServiceUrl(_ctx).GetTarget2(hash);
        int a = 0;

        foreach (Model.Data.DAO.Url i in t)
        {
            
            if (i != null)
            {
                a=a+1;
            }
        }
        if (a==0)
        {
            return new TimeoutExceptionObjectResult(error: "Not Found",503);
        }else
        if (DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now, t.ElementAt(0).ExpireAt) > 0)
        {
            t.ElementAt(0).state = "expire";
            _ctx.Entry(t.ElementAt(0)).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
            return new TimeoutExceptionObjectResult(error: "Url expiré",501);
        }
         string url= t.ElementAt(0).UrlOrigin;
        Console.Write(url);
        return new Redirect(url);
    }
```

the GetTarget2 method :

```
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Url>> GetTarget2(string hash)
    {
       var t2 = await _ctx.Url.Where(u => u.UrlShort == hash).ToArrayAsync();

        return  t2;
    }
```

and the entity :

```
    [Table("Url")]
public class Url
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UrlShort { get; set; }
    public string UrlOrigin { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public int Customer_id { get; set; }
    public int? targetItemId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpireAt { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<Stats> GetStats { get; set; }

    public Url()
    {

    }
    public Url(int Id,string UrlShort,string UrlOrigin,string state,int Customer_id,DateTime CreatedAt,DateTime ExpireAt)
    {
        this.Id = Id;
        this.UrlShort = UrlShort;
        this.UrlOrigin = UrlOrigin;
        this.state = state;
        this.Customer_id = Customer_id;
        this.CreatedAt = CreatedAt;
        this.ExpireAt = ExpireAt;
    }
}
```

when i try to pass a code which is in database i get this : `Not found` which means it does not find it in database

Update:
the database context declaration :

```
private readonly DatabaseContext _ctx;
```

and its definition :

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Url> Url { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Stats> Stats { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: I would first check whether _ctx.Url contains anything. If it does, then loop through it checking the ShortUrl values. Is your desired code really there?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock how can i check if _ctx.Url contains something? with this ? _ctx.Url.Where(u => u!=null && u.UrlShort == hash).ToArrayAsync();

Comment: Do you know how to debug?  Put a break on this line and examine _ctx.Url.  Check how many items it has.  Drill down into one or two items to check UrlShort.  Keep it simple.  You can work on the Linq when you are sure that you have values.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly then you are trying to redirect to another action method by reading the URL from the database. If the retured Url belongs to your application and just have the dynamic parameter then you can try **RedirectToAction** method for the redirect.

**Syntax:**

```
return RedirectToAction("ActionName", new { id = 90 });
```

*The will cause a redirect to YourApp/Controller/ActionName/90*

All you have to create an action method with argument (if required) and redirect from another action method from where you are getting url.

Alternativly you can also use

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", new RouteValueDictionary( 
    new { controller = "NameOfController", action = "Index", id = id } ) 
);
```

Comment: no my goal is to make a redirection to a url,not to another Controller, i insert the url into the redirect method and i would like this to work, or if there is another method for that it will be good

Comment: If you want to redirect to another url then why don't you just returned that url from you controller and let your UI handle this redirection, because redirection from the API controller doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: the problem is that The redirect method tells me its content is null or empty altough the fact i succeeded to print the value in terminal

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the Redirect method which indicates its content was null or empty although i printed the url in terminal successfully. So What i did is adding a prefix (http://) like this Redirect("http://"+url), url is the url coming from the database. if the url already contains the prefix http or https i remove it before passing it as parameter inside Redirect method. Doing this solved my problem.